# VTD-XML: how to execute XPath query not from the root element

Tags: java, xml, xpath, vtd-xml

I need to handle large XML files, and I decided to move from DOM parser to VTD-XML.

When I used Java's DOM parser, I could evaluate XPath queries from any node, not from the root. Look at [XPath.evaluate](http://goo.gl/3Je5Q) prototype:

```
Object evaluate(String expression,
                Object item,
                QName returnType)
                   throws XPathExpressionException
```

`Object item` is the starting context (a node, for example). This is very useful.

But I can't find the way to do the same in VTD-XML. I have read its API and read many examples, for instance, [this one](http://goo.gl/3Je5Q), but everywhere queries are executed from the root.

How to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, it seems I got it: actually, XPath queries are always executed relative to the current `VTDNav`'s cursor position.

Check out [this example](http://goo.gl/vcPUa), look for the section "Nested XPath support".